# Non-linear interaction terms in Stata

Tags: interaction, stata

I have a continuous dependent variable `polity_diff` and a continuous primary independent variable `nb_eq`. I have hypothesized that the effect of `nb_eq` will vary with different levels of the continuous variable `gini_round` in a non-linear manner: The effect of `nb_eq` will be greatest for mid-range values of `gini_round` and close to 0 for both low and high levels of `gini_round` (functional shape as a second-order polynomial).

My question is: How this is modelled in Stata? 
To this point I've tried with a categorized version of `gini_round` which allows me to compare the different groups, but obviously this doesn't use data to its fullest. I can't get my head around the inclusion of a single interaction term which allows me to test my hypothesis. My best bet so far is something along the lines of the following (which is simplified by excluding some `if`-arguments etc.):
`xtreg polity_diff c.nb_eq##c.gini_round_squared, fe vce(cluster countryno)`,
but I have close to 0 confidence that this is even nearly right.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I might do it:

```
sysuse auto, clear
reg price c.weight#(c.mpg##c.mpg) i.foreign
margins, dydx(weight) at(mpg = (10(10)40))
marginsplot
margins, dydx(weight) at(mpg=(10(10)40)) contrast(atcontrast(ar(2(1)4)._at) wald)
```

We interact weight with a second degree polynomial of mpg. The first margins calculates the average marginal effect of weight at different values of mpg. The graph looks like what you describe. The second margins compares the slopes at adjacent values of mpg and does a joint test that they are all equal.

I would probably give weight its own effect as well (two octothorpes rather than one), but the graph does not come out like your example:

```
reg price c.weight##(c.mpg##c.mpg) i.foreign
```